# Wha does synchronous usage of setTimeout stops the code if using await?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, settimeout

The following code brings just
"before timeout" and "within"
but not "after timeout".
why is this ?

```
async function asy() {
   console.log('before timeout');
   await awa();
   console.log('after timeout');
}

async function awa() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(function(){console.log('within');}, 600);
}

asy();
```

Comment: And the language is? `async/await` was first introduced by C#. That's not C#

Comment: Pretty sure this is JavaScript @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Liam or Typescript, which is why I asked instead of editing

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript, this will run in both but ultimately it's Javascript. Probably running on node but OP will need to confirm this

Comment: The callback needs to call resolve()?

Comment: Because of that, promise is never resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't resolved the Promise after returning and hence the output

```
async function asy() {
   console.log('before timeout');
   await awa();
   console.log('after timeout');
}

async function awa() {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(function(){
           console.log('within');
           resolve();
   }, 600);
}

asy();
```

`await` waits till the `Promise` is `resolved` or `rejected` before executing the following expressions

Answer (score 1):

Because you are never resolving the promise, so it's hanging forever.

```
return new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(function(){console.log('within');}, 600);
                   ^^^^^^^
                  NEVER USED
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the async before the function awa():

```
async function asy() {
    console.log('before timeout');
    await awa();
    console.log('after timeout');
}

function awa() {
  return new Promise(
    resolve => {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log('within'); resolve();}, 600);
    });
}

asy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the promise

```
   this.driverWait = async function (explicitWaitMS) {
        // create a new promise inside of the async function
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => resolve(true), explicitWaitMS) // resolve
        });

        // wait for the promise to resolve
        await promise;
    }
```